# Como utilizar ng-repeat dentro da biblioteca ui-carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directives

O carousel funciona, porém não estou conseguindo fazer ng-repeat dentro da diretiva, como poderia resolver isso?

No controller tenho a coleção:

```
$scope.steps = [
    {id:1, text: 'nnoonon 1', current:1, collection:[]},
    {id:2, text: 'nnoonon 2', current:2, collection:[1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {id:3, text: 'nnoonon 3', current:3, collectiom:[]}
];
```

Na view:

```
<ui-carousel
    slides="steps"
    slides-to-show="1"
    slides-to-scroll="1"
    autoplay="false"
    autoplay-speed="2000"
    dots="false">
    <carousel-item>
        {{item.id}}<br>
        {{item.text}}<br>
         <!-- MOSTRA A COLEÇÃO -->
        {{item.collection}}
         <div ng-show="item.current == 2"> 

           <!-- O NG-REPEAT NÃO FUNCIONA AQUI ??? -->
              <div ng-repeat="c in item.collection">{{c}}</div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </carousel-item>

</ui-carousel>
```

[**Esta é a biblioteca**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-carousel) que estou utilizando.

Para auxiliar, fiz um [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gT3X2qHYQpkEl99CKL1W?p=preview) do que preciso

Comment: Amigo, você consegue portar um exemplo no Plunker?

Comment: Aqui tem um plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/oM71yu/

Comment: Me ajuda para te ajudar amigo, a demo pura deles está no site deles, adapte sua lógica de "steps" nesse plunker por favor. Leia mais sobre [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jackson, eu coloquei na pergunta o plunker adaptado.

Comment: Não sei se isso ajuda, mas tem um `</div>` a mais do que deveria...

Comment: Este plugin aparentemente está bugado amigo, teu laço estava incorreto, por ter 2 arrays, você precisa fazer 2 níveis de NG-REPEAT. Mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Variáveis do controle não funcionam dentro do slide, este plugin torna o que há nele private. Eu trocaria para um outro. => http://plnkr.co/edit/vo42VSAO2dAm9q8NDsSg?p=preview

Comment: pelo que vi, o plugin mata o ng-repeat depois de carregado.

Comment: Tente criar uma variável test no controller com valor qualquer, e tente chama-lo dentro do carrosel, ele não funciona. Acho bem ruim isso =/

Comment: o problema é que ele compila o carrosel. na template.

Comment: `var compiledElement = $compile(templateInstance)($scope);
      el.addClass('ui-carousel').html('').append(compiledElement);`

Comment: tentei usando ng-include também não funciona.